# Navigation Drawer Layout Open

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm developing an Android application, I use navigation drawer as layout, i would know if is It possible that when the application starts the side menu remains open.

Actually At startup the menù remains closed.

Comment: add mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList); on activity oncreate methode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

will open your drawer, so you just need to call it on start up of your activity, for example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); // you can change the gravity to right if your drawer is rtl


}
```

any problem, just ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

where

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```